# Use PHP implode + array to return a comma separated list?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I working on some WordPress code with the WP Alchemy class, and I'm trying to recall the meta values used in a page template as a comma separated list. However when WP Alchemy Meta Boxes store the values into the domain, they aren't saved with delimiters nor spaces, so it's much like: onetwothreefourfive...

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $custom_metabox->get_the_id(), TRUE); ?>
<li>Via: <?php foreach ($meta['g2m_via'] as $link) { ?><a href="<?php echo $link['g2m_via-link']; ?>">
<?php
$prefix = ', ';
$words = array();
$words[] = $link['g2m_via-title'];
$words = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $words)));
for($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++){ $fruitlist = implode(', ', $words); print_r($fruitlist); } 
?></a><?php } ?></li>
```

$link['g2m_via-title'] is simply the name of the link that is stored in the meta field, i.e. Link1 would be the name, google,,com would be the link (which is not important here, I have that working). The other variables are all there. The $prefix variable does nothing, it was meant to act as a separator, like: $val .= $prefix . '' $link['g2m_via-title']; . ''; however, it causes: Link1, Link 1,Link 2, Link 1, Link 2, Link 3.

So far with that code, I've gotten the closest to what I want:

```
Link1Link2Link3
```

But it needs to be: `Link1, Link2, Link3`, and so on without the comma on the last link title.

Output of var_dump($link):

```
array(2) { 
    ["g2m_via-title"]=> string(7) "JoyStiq" 
    ["g2m_via-link"]=> string(22) "joystiq.com"; 
}JoyStiq 
array(2) { 
    ["g2m_via-title"]=> string(9) "GrindGadget" 
    ["g2m_via-link"]=> string(16) "grindgadget.com"; 
} GrindGadget 
array(2) { 
    ["g2m_via-title"]=> string(13) "Engadget" 
    ["g2m_via-link"]=> string(13) "engadget.com"; 
} Engadget
```

What I WANT it to look like so ["g2m_via-title"] will stop duplicating:

```
array[1] { 
    ["g2m_via-title"]=> "JoyStiq" 
    ["g2m_via-link"]=> "joystiq.com"; 
}
array[2] { 
    ["g2m_via-title"]=> "GrindGadget" 
    ["g2m_via-link"]=> "grindgadget.com"; 
}
array[3] { 
    ["g2m_via-title"]=> "Engadget" 
    ["g2m_via-link"]=> "engadget.com"; 
}
```

3 of the countless other pieces of code that I've tried: http://pastebin.com/wa0R8sDw.

Comment: what is the value of `$link['g2m_via-title']`?

Comment: What does `$link['g2m_via-title']` contain exactly?

Comment: Oh sorry, $link['g2m_via-title'] contains the name of the link (i.e. Link 1).

Comment: Can you give output of `var_dump($link);`. So I could know how it's stored.

Comment: array(2) { ["g2m_via-title"]=> string(7) "JoyStiq" ["g2m_via-link"]=> string(22) "http://joystiq.com" } JoyStiq array(2) { ["g2m_via-title"]=> string(9) "GrindGadget" ["g2m_via-link"]=> string(16) "http://grindgadget.com" } GrindGadget array(2) { ["g2m_via-title"]=> string(13) "Engadget" ["g2m_via-link"]=> string(13) "http://engadget.com" } Engadget

^Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Where does `$link` come from? Do you have multiple `$link`s? Is that piece of code in a loop?

Comment: No, the $link is by itself (just check the code in index.php). That's the only code in that file that relates to the problem.

Comment: Please summarize your question to only the essential information like an example of input and the corresponding output.

Comment: It is incomprehensible what your situation is. Please just post a clean, formatted `var_dump` of the relevant variables **into your question** and specify what the output should look like. The pastebin dump doesn't look very sensible somehow.

Comment: @deceze @GlitchMr @Jaitsu @Tatu Ulmanen I got it! 

`<ul class="sources">
        <?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $custom_metabox->get_the_id(), TRUE); ?>
        <li>Via: <?php foreach ($meta['g2m_via'] as $link) { ?><a href="<?php echo $link['g2m_via-link']; ?>"><?php $action = array(); $prefix = ', '; $action[] .= $prefix . '' . $link['g2m_via-title'] . ''; $action = implode(', ', $action); print_r($action);?></a><?php } ?>
        </li>`

It now comes out as:

, Joystiq , Like a G6 , Knockin Boots

Comment: The HTML is this:



The HTML is:

`Via: <a href="http://grindgadget.com">, JoyStiq</a><a href="http://lmfao.com">, Like a G6</a><a href="http://kb.com">, Knockin Boots</a>`

So NOW, how can I get the commas to be on the right side of the anchor links (outside of the links as well), and how can I cut off the last comma? Also, implode has no action in the code besides keeping it together, $prefix did all the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this data structure:

```
$links = array(
    array( 
        "g2m_via-title" => "JoyStiq",
        "g2m_via-link"  => "joystiq.com"
    ),
    array( 
        "g2m_via-title" => "GrindGadget",
        "g2m_via-link"  => "grindgadget.com"
    ),
    array( 
        "g2m_via-title" => "Engadget",
        "g2m_via-link"  => "engadget.com"
    )
);
```

This'll do:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output[] = sprintf('<a href="http://%s">%s</a>',
                        $link['g2m_via-link'],
                        htmlentities($link['g2m_via-title']));
}

echo join(', ', $output);
```

So will this in PHP 5.3+:

```
echo join(', ', array_map(function ($link) {
    return sprintf('<a href="http://%s">%s</a>',
                   $link['g2m_via-link'],
                   htmlentities($link['g2m_via-title']));
}, $links));
```

Comment: Actually, I still maintained the structure above, which is fine for now. But I'll definitely see if your code works now (the comma separation).